# How to completely disable `client_min_messages` in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

The C-driver for Postgres prints NOTICE messages to STD output.

How it could be disabled? I'm using STD output for logs and these unexpected messages breaks log parsing.

There's `client_min_messages` parameter that controls the level of messages, but I need to completely disable it, so even errors shouldn't be printed.

Is there a way to do that? I'm using PostgreSQL 13.2

Answer (score 0):

You could execute

```
SET client_min_messages = error;
```

to disable as many messages as possible. Note, however, that

> `INFO` level messages are always sent to the client.

as [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html) says.

But it would be way better to set up a notice handling function as detailed in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-notice-processing.html).

Comment: Oops, fixed. I should test.